# How to achieve Relative Content box with bootstrap 3.?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: I want to design this.]

I am new with bootstrap and css since i know i will have to create two column with 4 by 4 to achieve to content box in one section but what will make it look like as image above and also let it be responsive in different devices.

So far since yestarday i tried to work on it and i have been achieved this goal but still could not make it perfect. as mentioned in image.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<style>
  .gradient-color {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 20%, #e24301 100%);
    background-clip: text;
    text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue";
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .left-btn {
    float: left;
  }
  
  .first {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 4;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #280489 0%, #e24301 100%);
    border-image-slice: 1;
    height: auto;
    padding: 52px 60px 64px 49px;
  }
  
  .second {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    right: 200px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center heading">
      <h1>OUR STORY</h1>
      <div class="smaller-border text-center"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 first ">
      <p style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Sajaya Young Ladies was established under the name of Children Centers in 2004, and declared its independence in 2012, to focus on young ladies based on the vision of Her Highness Sheikha Jawaher bint Mohammad Al Qassimi.</p>
      <a class="gradient-btn gradient-color" style="padding: 10px;">More Details</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 second">
      <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/gdt5cK/Image_1.jpg" class="img img-responsive" alt="image">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Kamran, can you please explain in more details what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes sure. what  i am trying to achieve i have almost done like giving gradient border and make content and put button inside but what will be way to make div inside another like this

Comment: If you want to make a gradient border, you'll have to do a workaround. first, create a div with the desired gradient with some padding. after that, create a child element with a white background. this way, the padding will look like a border, but actually, it's the parent's background.

Comment: Not actually gradient it not so hard at all to achieve what i want to achieve is simply to overlap one div with another using bootstrap. same as it as in the picture it shows one container is overlaping another like that.

Comment: place both of them in a relative parent, and transform translate to -50% the content child

Comment: can you put it in answer like that just put two bootstrap 4by4 column div like that with any dummy content. it will be much better sorry if i am asking alot.